# How to retrieve records from DB using `CursorLoader` every time when i click on the button?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider, android-cursorloader

How to retrieve records from DB using `CursorLoader` every time when i click on the button?
First click: offset 0, count 30
Second click: offset 30, count 30
etc.
What i should to do: for each click restart the loader or something else?

Comment: is offset and count some top secret stuff you cannot talk about ?

Comment: Offset is start position of records in the table.
Count is a limit of returned records.

Comment: so you want a ListView or what ?

Comment: Finally yes. But i think it does not matter now. I just want to know how to load next part of data from db.

Comment: Cursor.moveToNext() moveToPrevious, moveToPosition

Comment: and moveToFirst and moveToLast

Comment: So i should to get all records (e.g. 2 millions) and use the navigation on the cursor?

Comment: 2 milions ??? no no no, in that case you need to use LIMIT clause in your SELECT statement and reload the loader when crossing the Cursor range

Comment: This answer i wanted to see. Thanks

Comment: your welcome, Dimitrij